# Thunderbird: Display new emails in folded threads more aggressively?

Tags: thunderbird, highlighting, unread-mail

When using the threaded view in Thunderbird, I have run into the problem, that it is easy to miss new mails, if the thread is folded. This is double important, because threads are folded by default.

Is there some way to change the highlighting method to make it harder to miss?

## Demonstration

1. A new top-level mail has arrived. The **bold** highlighting makes it easy to notice.
   [image]
2. The email is marked as read, remains in the inbox for now, e.g. because it contains actionable tasks.
   [image]
3. A follow-up email has arrived. The newly created group is folded by default, and its existence indicated only by a thin line.
   [image]